# Mutual Authentication - Empty reply from server

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, poco-libraries, mutual-authentication

I've been working with a web server, created with POCO C++ Libraries. I need to implement mutual authentication, so in the server, I've configured the verification mode as STRICT (SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT).

If I configure it as RELAXED (SSL_VERIFY_PEER), I can curl the server via HTTPS without problems, but when I try using the strict verification mode, the server and the client finish the handshake, and then the server doesn't respond, giving me as a result the "Empty reply from server" message.

I'm using the following curl:

```
curl -u user:pass --cert client.cert.pem:password --key client.key.pem --cacert ca-chain.cert.pem --capath /home/ca/ 'https://V.X.Y.Z:PORT' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br' -H 'Accept-Language: es-US,es;q=0.8,es-419;q=0.6,en;q=0.4' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36' --compressed --insecure
```

And I get this result:

```
*   Trying V.X.Y.Z...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to V.X.Y.Z (V.X.Y.Z) port PORT (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: ca-chain.cert.pem
  CApath: /home/ca/
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [62 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [1560 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [333 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
{ [42 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
} [4514 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [70 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
} [264 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=MX; ST=Sonora; L=Cajeme; O=Gustavo Inc; OU=Gustavo Systems; CN=CNName; emailAddress=gustavoinc@gmail.com
*  start date: Apr 11 18:07:27 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 21 18:07:27 2018 GMT
*  issuer: C=MX; ST=Sonora; O=Gustavo Inc; OU=Gustavo Systems; CN=Gustavo Inter; emailAddress=gustavoinc@gmail.com
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
} [5 bytes data]
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: V.X.Y.Z:PORT
> Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz
> Accept: application/json
> Connection: keep-alive
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
> Accept-Language: es-US,es;q=0.8,es-419;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
{ [2 bytes data]
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host V.X.Y.Z left intact
```

And it returns a status code 000.

As far as I can see, the handshake is being performed without problems. We perform the hello messages, the key exhange, we send our certs to identify ourselves, we agree on a protocol and a cipher-suite, and we can see the "SSL Certificate Ok" message, indicating that we authenticated correctly.
After that, we send our credentials for basic authorization purposes and then BAM, we get the "Empty reply from server" message. Also, we don't receive an "invalid credentials message", so it seems like it's not even reaching the server to check the credentials, like if the client and the server agreed with the cipher-suites, but then lost communication after that.

Do you have any idea of why this could be happening? Or am I missing something? I also tried using a web browser, but I'm, still getting the reponse timeout, so it doesn't seem like a problem with curl.

**Edit:** I'm also adding the full OpenSSL output after using the following OpenSSL command:

```
openssl s_client -connect url:port -cert client.cert.pem -key client.key.pem -pass pass:password -CAfile ca.cert.pem -msg -state -debug
```

Output: https://pastebin.com/he2j2FBy

Comment: 'SSL certificate verify ok.' means the client (curl/OpenSSL) determined the server cert is good -- it **does NOT mean the server likes your client cert**. In fact the response to your second flight (cCert  CKX CVer CCS Finished) is an Alert which indicates _some_ problem though this display doesn't confirm _what_ problem. Checking what the server logged is in general best; otherwise if you have (or get) OpenSSL you can get some more detail with `openssl s_client -connect $host:$port -cert $file -key $file [-pass $pw] [-CAfile $cafile] -msg`.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your help! I already tried with the s_client command using OpenSSL, and everything seems ok, except for this message "No client certificate CA names sent". I find it weird because I already tried sending both, the ca.cert file, and the ca-chain.cert files (both in PEM format). Also, both, the client and server certificates were signed using the same intermediate CA (and both are self-signed certificates).
**Edit**: Maybe this is happening because the server can't identify the client's certificate CA as a trusted CA?

Comment: For Poco, I _believe_  the library uses the same `SSL_Context` for both client and server. In this case, I _believe_ you need to modify the sources, create a client context and a server context, and then set the additional options in the client context. The last time I checked, there's only one SSL/TLS related file, so its not too much work.

Comment: @jww Hi, thanks for your help! Are you talking about creating another Poco app to work as a client? Because our final objective is to connect using a mobile application, and Poco will only be used for the server.

Comment: 'No client cert CA names' is because (per your pastebin) your server is sending CertReq with CA-list empty, which is unusual but permitted by protocol. OpenSSL (libssl) server does this unless the app or middleware (like Poco) explicitly calls `SSL_[CTX_]{set,add}_client_CA*` routines; it does not automatically use CA names from the truststore (as other implementations do). Also the list of client CAs requested and/or trusted is separate from the CA(s) used for the server cert. However, now I can't imagine why `curl` _and_ browser failed when `s_client` succeeded. ...

Comment: ... Did/does the server log anything relevant? Can you get an external trace with wireshark or tcpdump or similar (depending on your system) preferably using a capture filter that limits you to this connection so we don't need to wade through irrelevant material? (PS: using both `-msg -debug` on `s_client` is a waste, it makes the output twice as big without any benefit.) Add: on looking again I see that `s_client` did not send the intermediate cert, yet the server accepted, so clearly you must have at least intermediate in server's truststore, and possibly root as well depending on version.

Comment: Oh ok, then it seems like that message is just something informative, and not an error message. About the server, no, it seems like the server is not logging nothing relevant. And yeah, I talked with the guy configuring the server and told me that he added the intermediate and the CA certificates in the server to avoid a message asking him to confirm every connection with that certificate. I'll not have access to the server until tomorrow, but I'll play with tcpdump to capture the packets.
And again, Thanks for your help!